# Get-ADUser account name whose email address matches any of the emails indicated in csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a comma-separated csv file as below (first row is the header):

```
category;email.1;email.2;email.3;email.4;email.5;email.6
category1;sample@gmail.com;;;;;
category2;;;sample2@gmail.com;;;
category3;;sample3@gmail.com;;sample44@hotmail.com;;sample55@gmail.com
```

and so on...

Now I import it:

```
$emails = Import-CSV -Encoding Default -Delimiter ";" "c:\temp\myFile.csv"
```

And finally, for each row in the csv I want to get the AD user account name whose email address matches any from email.1 to email.6

So I try this using a foreach loop but I have no idea what have to put within it to get what I want.

```
$emails | foreach {
    $userAccountName = Get-ADUser -filter {something}
    # do some stuff with $userAccountName
}
```

Note: I would like a generic solution taking into account that in future can be more than 6 emails by category. Also take into account that some emails can be empty for the category.

Comment: If I've got you right it does not make sense to use a CSV file. A simple array would serve the same purpose. I just think you might not be able to use the `-Filter` parameter of the `Get-ADUser` though. Probably you will have to use a `Where-Object` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once imported you can enumerate the headers matching a pattern

```
$emails = Import-CSV -Encoding Default -Delimiter ";" "c:\temp\myFile.csv"
$EmailHeaders = ($Emails[0].psobject.Properties|Where-Object Name -like 'email.*').Name
```

ATM this returns:

```
> $EmailHeaders
email.1
email.2
email.3
email.4
email.5
email.6
```

Nest foreachs's to iterate the emails per row which are populated.
Get-ADUser commented out for testing

```
foreach($Row in $Emails){
  foreach($EmailHeader in $EmailHeaders){
    if($Email=$Row.$EmailHeader){
      [PSCustomObject]@{
        Category      = $Row.Category
        Email_x       = $EmailHeader
        Email         = $Email
        SamAccountName= $Null #(Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq "$Email"} -Properties SamAccountName).SamAccountName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Category  Email_x Email                SamAccountName
--------  ------- -----                --------------
category1 email.1 sample@gmail.com
category2 email.3 sample2@gmail.com
category3 email.2 sample3@gmail.com
category3 email.4 sample44@hotmail.com
category3 email.6 sample55@gmail.com
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the conditional? To check if email in that column for that row is empty, right? Also I guess you initialize $Email with the value of the correspondent column at the same time you check condition, right? Sorry I am very new to Powershell.

Comment: Yes, that's exaclty what the line does, If `$RoW.$EmailHeader` evaluates to $Null/empty the condition resolves to $False and the script block isn't executed. Otherwise `$Email` is set in one go.